# Subscribe inside subscribe: How to wait for both to finish in single subscription

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm new to RXJS and I have one thing that I want to achieve but I don't know how.

I Have 2 API calls. But the second one depends on the value of the first one. The problem is that I want to handle both calls with one subscribe so the finalize triggers when both subscriptions are finished. Here is how I do it now where the finalize triggers after first observable finishes and don't waits for second one.

```
private getTemplate(){
this.loading = true;
this.service.getTemplate()
.pipe(
  finalize(() => this.loading = false)
)
.subscribe(
  (response) => {
    if (response) {
       this.createImage(response.link);
    }
  }
)
```

}

```
public createImage(link: string) {
this.service.createImage(link)
.subscribe(
  (response) => {
    this.image = response;
  }
)
```

Comment: if you just want to call an api you can use the subscription as a promise with `<Observable>.toPromise()` and then just `await` it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would handle it with a `switchMap`

```
private getTemplate(){
  this.loading = true
  this.a2vService.getNetworkTemplate().pipe(
    filter(response => !!response),
    switchMap(response => this.createImage(response.link)),
    finalize(() => this.loading = false)
  ).subscribe()
}

public createImage(link: string) {
  return this.service.createImage(link).pipe(
    tap(response => {
      this.image = response
    })
  )
)
```

The `switchMap` will execute the second observable after the first one emitted. Since both Observables are in a single `pipe()`, you can put the `finalize()` here too which will trigger when the second observable emitted.

Also important to return the Observable from `createImage` so it can be used inside the `pipe()`.

As you can see, the `.subscribe()` is empty above. We can actually put the finalize stuff here and it should behave the same.

```
private getTemplate(){
  this.loading = true
  this.a2vService.getNetworkTemplate().pipe(
    filter(response => !!response),
    switchMap(response => this.createImage(response.link))
  ).subscribe(() => {
    this.loading = false
  })
}
```

---

How to pass the data from `getNetworkTemplate` to the `subscribe()` callback:

```
private getTemplate(){
  this.loading = true
  this.a2vService.getNetworkTemplate().pipe(
    filter(response => !!response),
    switchMap(response => 
      combineLatest([of(response), this.createImage(response.link)])
    )
  ).subscribe(([networkTemplateResponse, createImageResponse]) => {
    this.loading = false
  })
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. How would I do it if I need to use the data from .getNetworkTemplate() in subscribe? Here all you do on subscribe is loading = false but i need to alter some data here also that has nothing to do with .createImage(). 
This answer is okay regarding one subscription logic but this way on .subscribe() i get switchMap response data as response instead of .getNetworkTemplate() as response.

Comment: edited my answer to account for that

Answer (score 0):

You can use switchMap to subscribe to your second stream based on the result of the first. You can use filter to ensure you only move on to the second if the first response passes (`if (response)`).

You can write this something like this:

```ts
private getTemplate() {

  this.loading = true;
  this.a2vService.getNetworkTemplate().pipe(

    filter(response => !!response),
    switchMap(resp => this.service.createImage(resp.link)),
    finalize(() => this.loading = false)

  ).subscribe(resp => this.image = resp);
  
}
```